# Bitcoin listreceivedbyaddress as REST API

Tags: transactions, blockchain, address, python, deposit

I am currently looking for a REST API service which will allow me to implement a super simple deposit system.

Currently I am generating bitcoin addresses (mainnet + testnet) via Python. In addition to that I would like to retrieve all [incoming] transactions for a specific address, meaning only transactions where my address X is on the receiving side and excluded from the sending side.

I already explored blockcypher, blockchain.info, cryptoapis, etc.. but it really seems like no service can offer this super simple service..

Example:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc-testnet/address/tb1q5e2nhswlk8xl8qkzp98htnq80jx3ejlqegzav6

I just need to retrieve transactions including:

- 476062647c60a4fa2a3aa68aad7ea8198644b0667165c7adf1110eb28752d2f4
- 3f0cb4e6992b510b1ebac0304d17d71dd17804002d307f628853c3bf2270545a

Any ideas/suggestions?
Thanks!